# If $f,g: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ and $f\circ g=id_\mathbb{N}$, $f$ is invertible?

Tags: functions

If $f,g: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ and $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}_\mathbb{N}$

Is $f$ necessarily invertible?

I can't prove it formally, but also can't come up with two functions that contradict it.

Comment: $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is odd, and $f(x) = x/2$ if $x$ is even. This is surjective, but not injective.

Answer (score 5):

Take the function $$f:\Bbb{N}\to \Bbb{N} $$ by $f(1)=1, f(n)=n-1 \forall n >1$.
Take $g(n)=n+1$